# how to remove char (") from the begin and the end of a string?

Tags: c#, regex

how to remove char (") from the begin and the end of a string ?

ex:  `"1234"567"  ==>  1234"567`

thank's in advance

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
myString = myString.Trim('"');
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4tt83f9.aspx

Note that this will remove any amount of quotes at the beginning or the end of the string. If you only want to remove at most one from each end, see Anthony Pegram's answer. Or do it with regex:

```
myString = Regex.Replace(myString, "^\"|\"$", "");
```

Comment: Nice! Didn't know about overloading Trim.

Comment: It doesn't remove any amount of quotes at the beginning and the end as mentioned in the answer. It removes only first and last quotes that's good (testing with .net 5 / c# 9) i.e: [""ab cd""] -> ["ab cd"]