# What is the best way to trim double quotation in C#

Tags: c#, string

I have a string `"""`, which I need to trim the leading and tailing `"` and get the value `"`, what is the best way to do it?

If I just take the first and last character using `mystring.Substring(1,1)` and `Substring(mystring.Length-2,1 )` and compare with `"`, if they are equal, then take the substring of that again, is that too complicated? any short way to just trim the first and last `"` and keep the data value `"`? Thank you

**UPDATE:**
`"""` will be one of the case, for any another string wrapped with ", I can just `Trim('"')`, but if I do the same thing to it, it will be empty, and I do not know which pattern I would get later, if there is `"""""`. or `""""""""`, etc.

So in short, whatever that string look like, I just need to trim the first and last `"`, but for any strings like `"""""`, `"""""""...`, I would not expect empty value.

Comment: are always your first and last characters `"`?

Comment: Both ways you mentioned to get the first/last character should return the middle one. Is that intentional or am I misreading the question?

Comment: Why not using regex replace such as /^\"|\"$/ ?

Comment: I think there is something missing in this question

Comment: hi @TimSchmelter, that `"""` will be one of the case, for any another string wrapped with `"`, I can just `Trim('"')`, but if I do the same thing to it, it will be empty, and I do not know which pattern I would get later, if there is `"""""`. or `""""""""`, etc

Comment: @MarcoSalerno yes..

Comment: @gunr2171, that will return empty if I do `Trim('"')`

Comment: @LONG read the full answer

Comment: @gunr2171, will try that, ty!

Comment: @LONG: what would be the desired retult if it was `"""""`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter """

Comment: I've done it, and it works even with complex strings

Comment: @gunr2171, thank you, that place only the first and last `"`, problem solved, thank you.

Comment: @LONG: is your question including the **UPDATE** answered? If so, by which answer(mark as accepted). If it was answered with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2639918/how-to-remove-char-from-the-begin-and-the-end-of-a-string), then your answer should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, please close my question for me, it is answered from the comment link.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Regex.Replcae`, should look something like:

```
string pattern = @"\".*\"";
string replacement = "";
string input = ""asdf""asf"";
string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement);
```

Answer (score 0):

As with most similar questions, a Regex is the answer. Here is an Extension Method on a string that unquotes a string (meaning changes 'xxx' to xxx and "yyy" to yyy). It does NOT take care of unescaping quotes in the middle of the string (e.g. change '' to ' or \" to "), but that's usually a separate exercise using a different method. This one also removes any leading whitespace.

```
    /// <summary> Remove single or double quotes around an entry if any.  This also trims leading and trailing whitespace so
    ///           it's more like a positional parameter filter than pure unquoting. </summary>
    /// <param name="target"> Target string to unquote</param>
    /// <returns>             Trimmed and Unquoted string</returns>
    public static string UnQuote(this string target)
        => Regex.Replace(target, @"^\s*([\x22\x27])(.*)\1\s*$", "${2}");
```

Comment: The OP wants to handle unescaping quotes too, that's the main question.

Answer (score 0):

Done this way:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string str = "\"\"\"";
        str = TrimValueFromString("\"", str);
    }

    private static string TrimValueFromString(string value, string original)
    {
        string trimmed = original;
        if(original.IndexOf(value) == 0)
        {
            trimmed = original.Substring(value.Length);
        }
        if(trimmed.LastIndexOf(value) == (trimmed.Length - value.Length))
        {
            trimmed = trimmed.Substring(0, trimmed.LastIndexOf(value));
        }
        return trimmed;
    }
}
```

Input:

> """

Output:

> "

---

With this implementation you will be able to trim every string without cutting if the value is repeated, there is another example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string str = "asdciccioasdciccioasd";
        str = TrimValueFromString("asd", str);
    }

    private static string TrimValueFromString(string value, string original)
    {
        string trimmed = original;
        if(original.IndexOf(value) == 0)
        {
            trimmed = original.Substring(value.Length);
        }
        if(trimmed.LastIndexOf(value) == (trimmed.Length - value.Length))
        {
            trimmed = trimmed.Substring(0, trimmed.LastIndexOf(value));
        }
        return trimmed;
    }
}
```

Input:

> asdasdciccioasdciccioasdasd

Output:

> asdciccioasdciccioasd